# Python 3.4 why py2exe data_files are not being bundled?

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2exe

My environment:
Windows 10 x64 with
Python 3.4.4 [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

There is a simple Python script `c:\demo\script.py` that operates on files in `c:\demo\html\` folder.

There is `setup.py` file used with py2exe:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
from glob import glob

data_files = [("html", glob(r".\html\*.*"))]
# data_files = [("html", ["c:/demo/html/index.html"])]

py2exe_options = dict(
    optimize=2,
    compressed=True,
    bundle_files=1,
    dist_dir='dist1',
    )

setup(name="name",
      data_files=data_files,
      windows=[{'script' : "script.py"}],
      zipfile=None,
      options={"py2exe": py2exe_options},
)
```

I want data_files to be bundled into .exe file (when "zipfile=None" is used) or to a zipfile otherwise.

For some reasons data_files are never bundled in both cases.
`c:\demo\html` with it's content are just being copied to `c:\demo\dist1\html` while standard Python libs and interpreter are successfully bundled to .exe or .zip file depending on the config.

What is wrong with data_files? How to bundle them successfully?